# Setting more than one JAVA_HOME in windows

Tags: java, windows, java-home

I am having problem with setting JAVA_HOME.
I am having two different project which is having java dependency 1.6 and 1.7 respectively. Whenever i need to compile,every time i need to change JAVA_HOME. 
My Question is : can i able to set JAVA_HOME like this :

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_07\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\

is it possible or any other solution?

Comment: Use a batch file to launch your IDE, and in that batch file, set JAVA_HOME appropriately.

Comment: Maybe using only the jdk1.7, and compile with `javac -target 1.6 -source 1.6` ?

Comment: @Bathsheba could you please elaborate. Thanks.

Comment: +1 @Nizil Thanks,i am able to do this using eclipse/ant. but i am having problem where my code is compiled in jdk 1.6 and java_home set was 1.7 and if i am trying to run then it is giving some unnoticed problem.

Comment: I have the same problem may be this will help you. https://blogs.oracle.com/pranav/switch-between-different-jdk-versions-in-windows